# Initialization of a static const variable

Tags: c++, static

I am bit confused about the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(const string& str)
{
    static const char * const c = str.c_str();
    cout << c << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   test("Hello");
   test("Nooo");
   return 0;
}
```

Since the variable `c` is declared as `static` and `const`, shouldn't this be initialized only once and keep its initial value until the process is completed? According to this reasoning, I was expecting the following output:

```
Hello
Hello
```

But I got:

```
Hello
Nooo
```

Can you clarify why the value of the variable `c` has been modified between two function calls even though it is a `const` variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your program has **undefined behavior**.

When you pass `"hello"` to `test`, a temporary `std::string` object is created, and from that string `c` is constructed (which is just a pointer to the data of the string object).

When the function call ends, the temporary `std::string` object is destroyed, and `c` becomes a dangling pointer. Using it again is undefined behavior.

In your case, the second temporary `std::string` object's data has the exact same memory address as the first one, so `c` points to that data. This is not guaranteed whatsoever.

Comment: Actually it isn't undefined. **Dereferencing** it is undefined. Since it always has a valid address when dereferenced, it's a valid program.

Comment: @StoryTeller, `cout << c << endl;` does dereference the pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller The output operator uses dereferencing.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Reading the content pointed to by `c` is actually **dereferencing**. dereferencing doesn't necessary mean the usage of `*` as you might probably think.

Comment: @Nawaz, the value is read *inside* the scope where the pointer is valid.

Comment: @StoryTeller, it does not get updated with the new address. `c` is a `static` variable and is initialized only in the first call to the function.

Comment: @StoryTeller The first time it is valid.  The second time it still points to the old string that was destroyed.  That is the UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Pointer is not valid for the second call. It points to a destroyed object.

Comment: @NathanOliver Gah. That is one of the most annoying things with copy initialization syntax. Turn the initialization into a separate assignment, and the program is valid. I need my coffee.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes but then you have a initialization(default construction) and a assignment which at best is the same performance but in many cases it has less performance.

Comment: @NathanOliver, negligible for pointers. Especially for a static.

Answer (score 1):

You have Undefined Behaviour in your code so those results may vary. The UB is because call `test("Hello");` creates a temporary which then you assign to static local variable. This temporary is destoryed after a call ends, so the pointer in test function is dangling. If you use it then you have undefined behaviour.

It is possible that memory manager reuses the same memory region, so that you see Hello and Nooo in your results.